# Can you use an MVC Based Web Project with ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to understand how to go about this.  So I know Service Stack has a razor plugin.  So does that mean you create a regular Web Project (non ASP.NET MVC based project) and then use the Stack Plugin?

If you don't want to use the Stack razor plugin, then I assume you go with the standard ASP.NET MVC project type (without WebAPI scaffolding) and then use razor that way.  But then I wonder what else you have to take out or ignore if going this route if using the ServiceStack for everything else or do you not need to worry about any clutter that is inside the MVC project that is not used if we are utilizing most of ServiceStack's functionality?

just need some more insight on it, I don't see much about that in the docs at least yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, the answer is 'yes.'

In particular, you may wish to examine this [sample project based on [a] MVC4 default template. Shows how to use ServiceStack Authentication together with MVC4 controllers. How to invoke services which require authentication and shows how to use ServiceStack Session to store variables.](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/tree/master/CustomAuthenticationMvc)

Comment: thanks.  Why would one who is doing MVC not want to use MVC4 with ServiceStack?  I am just trying to understand the various setups that people might have tried...

Comment: Couldn't say.  I've never used MVC, or ASP, for anything.